# How could I group a list of strings into a list of different sublist

Tags: python, list, loops, sublist

I have a list of strings as the example below.

```
list = ['#4008 (Pending update)',
 'Age 1 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 '#4007 (Pending update)',
 'Onset date',
 'Asymptomatic',
 'Confirmed date',
 '-',
 '+'
 '#4006 (Pending update)',
 'Age 65 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 'Place of residence',
 '-']
```

I am going to group the strings into a sublists of list as below,
where if a string is starting with '#' then I would group it with the strings behind it until the next string that starts with '#' appear.

```
[['#4008 (Pending update)',
 'Age 1 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-'],

 ['#4007 (Pending update)',
 'Onset date',
 'Asymptomatic',
 'Confirmed date',
 '-',
 '+'],

['#4006 (Pending update)',
 'Age 65 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 'Place of residence',
 '-']]
```

```
new_list = []
sub_list
n = 0
for i in list:
    if i[0].startswith('#'):
        try i[0+1].
        sub_list.append(i)

new_list.append(sub_list)
new_list
```

My idea is starting with the index 0 string and check strings one by one and break the loop when next string starts with # appear. Then the searching loop starts again to group the next sublist but I have no idea how to write the code now. How could it can be achived, thanks

Comment: whats that try statement supposed to do

Comment: I want it to check whether the next string is starting with '#' so I used except to break the checking if the next string is starting with '#' and from a sublist. But it seems not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = ['#4008 (Pending update)',
 'Age 1 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 '#4007 (Pending update)',
 'Onset date',
 'Asymptomatic',
 'Confirmed date',
 '-',
 '+',
 '#4006 (Pending update)',
 'Age 65 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 'Place of residence',
 '-']

out = []
for val in lst:
    if val.startswith('#'):
        out.append([val])
    else:
        out[-1].append(val)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=40)
```

Prints:

```
[['#4008 (Pending update)',
  'Age 1 Female',
  'Onset date',
  '-'],
 ['#4007 (Pending update)',
  'Onset date',
  'Asymptomatic',
  'Confirmed date',
  '-',
  '+'],
 ['#4006 (Pending update)',
  'Age 65 Female',
  'Onset date',
  '-',
  'Place of residence',
  '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list_ = ['#4008 (Pending update)',
 'Age 1 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 '#4007 (Pending update)',
 'Onset date',
 'Asymptomatic',
 'Confirmed date',
 '-',
 '+'
 '#4006 (Pending update)',
 'Age 65 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 'Place of residence',
 '-']

result, tmp = [], []

for i, j in zip_longest(list_, list_[1:]):
    tmp.append(i)

    # if delimiter is found, push the tmp to result & reset tmp
    if j and j.startswith("#"):
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = []

# include value from last iteration.
result.append(tmp)
```

---

```
[['#4008 (Pending update)', 'Age 1 Female', 'Onset date', '-'],
 ['#4007 (Pending update)', 'Onset date', 'Asymptomatic', 'Confirmed date', '-', '+'],
 ['#4006 (Pending update)', 'Age 65 Female', 'Onset date', '-', 'Place of residence', '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can handle this with list comprehensions pretty handily:

```
some_list = [
    '#4008 (Pending update)', 'Age 1 Female', 'Onset date', '-',
    '#4007 (Pending update)', 'Onset date', 'Asymptomatic', 'Confirmed date', '-', '+',
    '#4006 (Pending update)', 'Age 65 Female', 'Onset date', '-', 'Place of residence', '-'
    ]

starts = [index for index, string in enumerate(some_list) if '#' in string] + [-2]
# The addition of -2 ensures that the final item in the list is captured

new_list = [some_list[start:stop] for start, stop in zip(starts, starts[1:])]
```

Given your input data, it takes about 1/2 the time of a for loop:

**List comprehension**: 1.87 µs ± 157 ns per loop

**For loop**: 3.95 µs ± 232 ns per loop

Comment: it seems that the last string ('-') of the third sublist cannot be captured

Comment: @goxywood Whoops, modified -1 to -2. I keep forgetting python list slices are "up until, not including."

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with very simple logic. You can try the following code:

```
list = ['#4008 (Pending update)',
    'Age 1 Female',
    'Onset date',
    '-',
    '#4007 (Pending update)',
    'Onset date',
    'Asymptomatic',
    'Confirmed date',
    '-',
    '+',
    '#4006 (Pending update)',
    'Age 65 Female',
    'Onset date',
    '-',
    'Place of residence',
    '-']

new_list = []  # this will be the output list
temp_list = []  # holds sub lists

for item in list:  # iterate on each item in the list
    if item[0] == '#':  # of the list item starts with a #,
        # the previous temp list is a separate group
        new_list.append(temp_list)  # add the previous list in the output list
        temp_list = [item]  # create new group start with the current item
    else:
        temp_list.append(item)
new_list.append(temp_list)  # add the remaining last group

new_list = new_list[1:]  # remove the first group as it is empty
print(new_list)
```

with this, you will get the following output. You can easily prettify it!

```
[['#4008 (Pending update)', 'Age 1 Female', 'Onset date', '-'], ['#4007 (Pending update)', 'Onset date', 'Asymptomatic', 'Confirmed date', '-', '+'], ['#4006 (Pending update)', 'Age 65 Female', 'Onset date', '-', 'Place of residence', '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop the first dimension of newList is incremented every-time a new string starts with #. The other string elements without # are appended to the corresponding second dimension list.

```
list = ['#4008 (Pending update)',
 'Age 1 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 '#4007 (Pending update)',
 'Onset date',
 'Asymptomatic',
 'Confirmed date',
 '-',
 '+',
 '#4006 (Pending update)',
 'Age 65 Female',
 'Onset date',
 '-',
 'Place of residence',
 '-']

newList =[]
i = -1
for count,item in enumerate(list):
    if item.startswith('#'):
        i +=1
        newList += [[item]]
    else:
        newList[i] += [item]

print(newList)
```

Comment: It will be better for other landing to see the answer , if you could provide some brief about your answer.

Comment: In the loop the first dimension of newList is incremented every-time a new string starts with #. The other string elements without # are appended to the corresponding second dimension list.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, though it just seems like a crappier version of Andrej's answer :)

```
def group(l, key='#', inner=[], out=[]):
    for i, ele in enumerate(l):
        if ele.startswith(key):
            if i > 0:
                out.append(inner)
            inner = [ele]
        else:
            inner.append(ele)
    out.append(inner)
    return out

print(group(list))

[['#4008 (Pending update)', 'Age 1 Female', 'Onset date', '-'],
 ['#4007 (Pending update)',
  'Onset date',
  'Asymptomatic',
  'Confirmed date',
  '-',
  '+'],
 ['#4006 (Pending update)',
  'Age 65 Female',
  'Onset date',
  '-',
  'Place of residence',
  '-']]
```